# How to delete Index?

Tags: mysql

Further to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293273/why-is-ths-a-duplicate-key) (qv) ...

I have already created the table(s) and populated with data.  How do I set the prefix length to a very large value or remove it all togther, so that I don't have this problem? There will never be more than a few thousand rows and only this applciation is running on a dedicated PC, so performance is not an issue.

Solution, please for either PhpMyAdmin, or just MySQL command line.

---

Update: Can I just delete this index (or make it infinitely long)?

Hmmm, I would prefer to keep the unique index if I can. So, how to make it infinitely long?

Or should I redefine my text fields to be var_char with a limit to the length? (I do know the max possible lngth of the primary key)

```
mysql> describe tagged_chemicals;
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bar_code    | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| rfid_tag    | text    | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| checked_out | char(1) | NO   |     | N       |       |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll probably be something like

```
CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (name(10));
```

from create index documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

where in your case the rfid_tag is length 20.

Comment: and is there a syntax to say "don't limit the index, make it as long as the longest entry?"

Comment: "Prefix support and lengths of prefixes (where supported) are storage engine dependent. For example, a prefix can be up to 1000 bytes long for MyISAM tables, and 767 bytes for InnoDB tables." A quote from the document link above.

Comment: +1 sounds good ... but what does it mean? And how does it help me?

Comment: Indexes can be added or deleted after the table has been created.  If you know the maximum possible length of the rfid_tag you can create an index with the same prefix length.  The above tells you you can have a tag 1000 bytes long if the table uses the MyISAM engine.  Please spend some time with the documentation.